# Javascript - var being used in another var?

Tags: javascript, jquery, var

why do some people store a var within another var?

**For example:**

```
var checked = $("#filterControls :checkbox:checked");
var arr = checked
```

A more expansive view of the code below.

```
var checked = $("#filterControls :checkbox:checked");
if (checked.length) {
  rows.hide(200);
  var arr = checked
    .map(function() {
      return "." + $(this).val();
    })
    .get();
  var selector = arr.join("");
  $(selector).show(200);
}
```

Comment: `arr` is assigned the result of `checked.map(...).get(...)`, which is not the same as `checked`. And it's perfectly normal to store the result of a computation in a variable...

Comment: Ohhh right! I see now. Thank you

Comment: But I've seen legit use cases for assigning the same value to multiple separate variables. Most often is for keeping track of a malleable state while maintaining a record of the original value.

Answer (score 0):

You got a wrong idea about the `map` function. The `map` function is immutable, but it returns the modified entries. Because of that you have to assign it to a new value. So `checked` has the unmodifed values and `arr` has the values which were modified by `map`-function.